# Will indexes get used if you query a subset of the columns of the index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

So consider I have the following table:

table:

- id (Int, Primary Key)
- c1
- c2
- c3
- c4
- c5

Assume I use queries that differ at runtime (a website for example where checkboxes denote whether or not to search on a specific field), some possible instances:

(Using some `x, y, z` for the values)

- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = 1 AND c2 = 2`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = 1 AND c2 = 2 AND c3 = x AND c4 = y`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = 2 AND c2 = 3`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = 2 AND c2 = 3 AND c5 = z`

The questions:

1. What is the effect of an index on `(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)`? How will it be used in the several queries?
2. What would the best indexes be to create on this table?

Comment: I think it depends on the subset

Comment: @Strawberry Where can I find about in what way it depends on the subset?

Comment: In the manual. :-) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL documentation does a good job of explaining how multi-column indexes work [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

In general, the index can be used for a `where` clause when some number of column on the *leftmost* side of the index have equality conditions.  Your `where` clauses use the following columns:

- c1, c2
- c1, c2, c3, c4
- c1, c2
- c1, c2, c5

Any index starting with columns `c1` and `c2` would normally be used for these queries.  MySQL can apply other conditions to using the index, such as selectivity.  That is, if `c1` and `c2` have constant values (for instance) then using an index will not benefit the query.

To optimize all these combinations, you can create two indexes:  `c1, c2, c3, c4` and `c2, c1, c5`.   The reason for swapping `c1` and `c2` in the second index is so you *could* handle queries where the condition is on `c2` but not `c1`, as well as the reverse.

Comment: And if I am correct the order of the `WHERE` clause itself does not matter? I hope MySQL is smart enough to figure that out on it's own. I understand that it cannot be done as the indexes are stored physically.

Comment: @skiwi . . . The order of conditions in the `where` (or `on` clause) does not matter.  However, equality is quite different from inequality.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `ìndex on (c1,c2,c3)` the database will create and index good for searching `... where c1=sth and c2=sth` with or without c3.

This will perform better than seperate indices.

But is is somehow useless if you need only `C2` as where clause

if you need `c3` as only indext col, too, then create an additional index for it.